# Terminal: Multi-column/Table 'ls'

Tags: bash, terminal

When running a fullscreen terminal, `ls` doesn't adapt to the current terminal width and supply me with multiple column-listings of items, it always provide a single column of directory items. Even while using a full-blown `ls -alF`, I am still not even using half the screen-estate.

I guess this is by design and all, but are there any alternatives to ls that actually takes advantage of the current terminal width and provides output accordingly, for example in a table format?

Comment: After you resize your terminal, enter `reset` to see if it will adjust to the new rows and cols.

Comment: That did the trick. Odd!

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  Asking what to replace `ls` with is assuming the answer to your _real_ problem.  [Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the european currency systems.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)  Put the output of `stty -a`, before and after resizing your terminal emulator's window, into your question.